# Set request timeout on RXMoyaProvider

Tags: alamofire, rx-swift, moya, rxalamofire

I am using Moya with RxSwift and I am trying to set the request timeout for the network call (API Calls) using below code as suggested :

which is including the custom Alamofire Manager when declaring your Provider

```
lazy var provider: RxMoyaProvider<CAPProviderAPI> = {
    return RxMoyaProvider<CAPProviderAPI>(endpointClosure: Utility.getEndPointClosure(forProviderType: .authorized), manager: DefaultAlamofireManager.sharedManager, plugins: [NetworkActivityPlugin(networkActivityClosure: networkActivityClosure)])
}()
```

but I am getting an error saying : Use of unresolved identifier 'networkActivityClosure'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to share with you the way I did it. It might not answer your question, but it shows the way to achieve the desired behavior using **RxSwift** operators.

I have some function which accepts timeout parameter and makes a request:

```
func request(timeout: TimeInterval, ...other params) -> Observable<...>
```

Inside this function I transform timeout to `Observable` this way:

```
func observableTimeout(timeout: TimeInterval, ...other params) -> Observable<...> {
    return Observable<Int>
        .timer(timeout, period: ..., scheduler: ...)
        .take(1)
        .map(to: ...) // map to timeout error
}
```

If the timeout takes place - I need to cancel the request. I have made some `flatMapLatest` analogue which also accepts a cancel signal:

```
public extension Observable {
    public func flatMapLatest<T>(cancel: Observable<T>, factory: @escaping (E) throws -> Observable<T>) -> Observable<T> {
        let observableNormal = self
            .flatMap({ try factory($0) })
        return Observable<Observable<T>>
            .of(cancel, observableNormal)
            .merge()
            .take(1)
    }
}
```

As a result, the request function will work this way:

```
func request(timeout: TimeInterval, ...other params) -> Observable<...> {
    let cancel = observableTimeout(timeout: timeout, ...)
    let factory = ...// your observable factory which makes a request using Moya
    return Observable
        .just((), scheduler: ...)
        .flatMapLatest(cancel: cancel, factory: factory)
}
```